# Airflow email sender name

Tags: airflow

In Airflow's config, `airflow.cfg`, you set the email address that failure/other notifications get sent from with

```yaml
[smtp]
smtp_mail_from = airflow@example.com
```

When this email comes in, the sender's "name" is the same as the email address. Is there any way to customize this name? For example "Airflow Admin", "Airflow Notices", etc.